# Huge lag after using imagepng

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a scenario where a user uploads an image file. I strip the background color (defined as the upper left corner's color)...and save to file with imagepng.

I originally tried echoing some html that directly called that file name, but it would take as long as seven minutes for the image to appear (this is a 6k file, nothing fancy). I read that you should not try to use the posted data in the same request, so, instead of outputting the image, I changed it to a link to a second page, which would get the image.

But the same lag occurs. I have not done much image manipulation, so appreciate any guidance as where I've gone wrong, or ways to speed things up. My eventual goal is that the user might be uploading 10+ images at a time

Here's the primary code, the `viewing_page.html` was just `<img src="target.png"/>`

```
<?php
if($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']){
    //some validation is necessary, this is just a proof of concept for a friendly user test
    if($_FILES['test']['type']=="image/png"){
        $im = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']);
    }
    if(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']);
    }
    if($_FILES['test']['type']=="image/gif"){
        $im = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['test']['tmp_name']);
    }
    //determine background RGB
    $rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    $background = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
    // Make the background transparent
    imagecolortransparent($im, $background);
    imagepng($im,'target.png');
    imagedestroy($im);
    echo "<a href=\"viewing_page.html\">View</a>";
    //echo "<img src=\"target.png\"/>"; //-----------this was my first (and preferred) approach
    }
else{
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#00CCFF">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="test" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: how long does it take for small images uploaded? be specific!

Comment: 422 seconds to download, 0.25 to upload. I thought the below answer was working, but now it turns out that even if the IMAGE comes back quickly, a supporting JS file lags...also 422 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does imagepng really take so long to generate the .png file or does your web server not serve the image until it has 7 minutes of age? On my system (Linux, PHP 5.3.6) and with your code the image is available immediately.

Comment: Well, the image is created immediately, and I can see it on the server (via dreamweaver or phpadmin at my host) but I guess it's not being served fully because I can't access it either in this script, or directly in a new window...that's why I thought maybe I was doing something wrong with imagepng...(php 5.2.17, linux)...

Comment: To me this sounds like a problem with your hosting provider. Maybe they have requests for image files go through layers of cache and the cache is not checking the storage and that causes the lag. Does the same thing happen with images you upload manually?

Comment: I just got off the phone with them and they also get instant results...there must be something wrong with my local machine/environment (I'm in a heavy security location). Thanks for your help